# MatLab: displaying figures side by side

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

As when you use `subplot` to display plots side by side in the same window, I would like a similar function that can do the same for multiple figures. This works:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
```

and I am looking for something like this:

```
subfigure(2,2,1)
```

Does a build-in function with this advantage exist?

Comment: What does subplot not do that you require?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, i guess that he wants different colormaps for indexed images. I had the same problem once.

Comment: @Andrey If that is indeed the problem, you can try [freezeColors/unfreezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors-unfreezecolors) from the file exchange.  It has worked nicely for me.  As far as the question goes, nothing is built-in as far as I know, though there is a `subfigure` submission on the file exchange as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write one such function yourself. The idea is to get the screen size:

```
get(0,'ScreenSize')
```

then divide it up into sub-regions according to the input parameters. You would also need to account for margins in-between.

Another idea:

- create an invisible figure (preferably same aspect ratio as the screen)
- call `subplot` inside it
- capture the position of the created axis
- delete figure
- scale the position captured to fit the screen size, and use it to create the actual figures.